# jar file is not displaying in docker container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I have an sbt project and i am creating its Jar using the  `sbt publishLocal` command and i want a docker image for that i am doing something like this

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER Sara Waheed <sarawaheed3191@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /myproject

ADD . /myproject

# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt", "publishLocal"]
```

and i am building it `docker build -t myproject:v1` and run it `docker run myproject:v1`
i have seen in the logs

```
[info] Main Java API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /stripe-payment-account/target/myproject-1.0.1-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] :: delivering :: com.test#myproject;1.0.1 :: 1.0.1 :: release :: Tue May 07 10:26:13 UTC 2019
[info]  delivering ivy file to /stripe-payment-account/target/ivy-1.0.1.xml
[info]  published myproject to /root/.ivy2/local/com.test/myproject/1.0.1/poms/myproject.pom
[info]  published myproject to /root/.ivy2/local/com.test/myproject/1.0.1/jars/myproject.jar
[info]  published myproject to /root/.ivy2/local/com.test/myproject/1.0.1/srcs/myproject-sources.jar
[info]  published myproject to /root/.ivy2/local/com.test/myproject/1.0.1/docs/myproject-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /root/.ivy2/local/com.test/myproject/1.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 77 s, completed May 7, 2019, 10:26:13 AM
```

and when i try to look the file contents of this container via

```
docker exec -t -i containerid /bin/bash
```

and look into

```
cd ///root/.ivy2
```

and ls -a only shows

```
.  ..  .sbt.ivy.lock  cache
```

the local folder is missing here but when i run the container it shows that it created the jar in `/root/.ivy2/local/com.test/myproject/1.0.1/docs/myproject-javadoc.jar`

why its not showing the local folder in `.ivy2` folder what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're checking `/root/.sbt/.ivy2 ` or `/root/.ivy2` ?

Comment: Sorry i am checking in root/.ivy2 and edited the question  as well